# How to avoid that multiple boostrapDialog open on the user keyUp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I digit the password. The password is composed from only numbers and evry time the user digits a letter key I show a boostrapDialog.
But if the user press quickly more keys, multiple dialog open at the same time.
The code is the following:

```js
 $('#passwd', $form)
            .on('keyup', function(e){
                if(!isNumberKey(e)){
                    this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1);
                    BootstrapDialog.alert({message: '<%=rb.getStringForJS("ALERT_PASSWORD_NUMBER")%>', type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER });
                }
            });
```

```html
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd"           placeholder="CIao" maxlength="12">
</div>
```

Is there any solution? Thanks in advance, any suggestion welcome!

Comment: please add dependencies to your snippet so that I can run and check the issue.
add jquery and bootstrap link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable to store the dialog status.

```
var isDialogOpen = false;
$('#passwd', $form)
            .on('keyup', function(e){
                //  If dialog is not opening
                if(!isNumberKey(e)  && !isDialogOpen){
                    this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.length - 1);
                    BootstrapDialog.alert({message: '<%=rb.getStringForJS("ALERT_PASSWORD_NUMBER")%>', type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER });

                     // Now it is opening
                     isDialogOpen = true;
                }
            });
```

And when you close the dialog, you must change the status.

```
isDialogOpen = false;
```